# Proportionally scale font-size in an HTML email to remove orphans

Tags: css, html-email

We have an HTML email with a one line title set at 16px Georgia inside a table cell.

We're using relative values so the table re-sizes for mobile, but that is producing orphans where only one word is on the second line.

Is there any technique where you could scale down the type proportionally to the table?

I know font-size could be set to a percentage, but wondering if there is any way to tie that to the re-size of the container.

Comment: There is no guarantee that this will make any difference. Different browsers and mail clients will render this differently. Perfectly aligning text in an email is an impossible and fruitless venture.

Comment: Only way to avoid orphans is to manually add line breaks.

Comment: Thanks -- I had a feeling that this just wasn't possible, but wanted to confirm there wasn't some hack or workaround I just wasn't aware of.

Comment: @jsuissa Actually samanthasquared's `&nbsp;` solution should work, although I have never tried it myself. If you replace `the last few words of your text` with `the&nbsp;last&nbsp;few&nbsp;words&nbsp;of&nbsp;your&nbsp;text` it should treat it as one word, orphaning the whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed two options to deal with orphans occurring in a responsive email:

- You can try `&nbsp;` instead of a normal space
- You can use `@media` to declare a smaller `font-size` for your email when it appears on a mobile device, see: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/coding/

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of the @media functionality, but wanted to see if there were any more automated options -- but had no idea that the way the space character could make a difference.